# How to set active link in Navbar using Nav.Link and React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to include a very basic Navbar on my site using React Router but either the styles or routes get messed up depending on what I change.

Here it says to use Navbar, Nav, and Nav.Link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props so I want to use these.

The problem is, it seems to me that the Nav.Link needs the href attribute to send the user to that route, for example /One. But then the One link at the top doesn't get active styles. If I remove the href attribute, it gets the active styles when I click on that link, but doesn't send the user to /One or load the component I want for that route obviously.

I don't see a SO answer about this that uses these tags, just answers using Link and NavLink which the URL I linked doesn't use. There isn't an example on that page either that uses multiple href attributes. What am I missing? Below is my code.

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" fixed="top">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#">MySite</Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link href="/" activeClassName="active" eventKey="/">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/one" activeClassName="active" eventKey="/one">One</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/two" activeClassName="active" eventKey="/two">Two</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" exact strict component={Redcircle} />
          <Route path="/one" exact strict component={Bluesquare} />
          <Route path="/two" exact strict component={Greentriangle} />
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected result: Navbar that changes url to /one, loads component Bluesquare, and makes the word One in the Navbar have active styles
Actual result: Either route loads or One has active styles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You [missed](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-props) `activeKey` prop from `Nav` component.
Just pass the param from router [HOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

**UPD:**
`activeClassName` provides by `react-router-dom` component, and as you can see `Nav.Link` has `active` prop, but there is no any relations between them.

The simplest way to resolve your issue is passing current path to `activeKey` prop in `Nav` component, and current path you may get from `pathname` field in `location` prop which provides by `withRouter`[HOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

**UPD2:** Here is [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/718p1ovkm1)

Comment: I am really new to this...this is my first attempt at a react app. Could you explain by editing the code I shared? I got the <Nav activeKey="/"> part but not sure about the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the code sandbox. Marked your answer as correct since it works, but what I ended up doing was use HashRouter rather than BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this.. It's working properly:

```
function Header()
{
    return(
        <Router>
        <div >
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/" eventKey="/">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="/footer" activeClassName="active" eventKey="/">About</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/count" activeClassName="active" eventKey="/">Count</Nav.Link>

          <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
            Dank memes
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
              </div>
              <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/'/>
                <Route path='/count' component={Count} />
                <Route path='/footer' component={Footer} />

              </Switch>
                </Router>
    );
}
```